# How update kubernetes 1.10.4 to 1.11

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade

I am using a Kubernetes cluster version `1.10.4`.  I want to update it to 1.12 but first, I need to update it to 1.11 how it is possible?

I read this FAQ:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-11/

But it did not work. Steps try to update immediately to 1.12 and that ending with an error. :(

Help!

Comment: Can you please post what errors you are facing while upgrading the cluster...

Comment: Kubernetes developers have always said, The General version must always be updated sequentially. 1.9 to 1.10, 1.10 to 1.11 etc.

Comment: Show us the errors, thx!

Comment: root@KUBERNETES1:# kubeadm upgrade plan
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[upgrade/config] FATAL: invalid configuration: kind and apiVersion is mandatory information that needs to be specified in all YAML documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced your issue  by installing v.1.10.4 version and trying to upgrade it to v.1.11.0 using https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-11/ FAQ.

The same error and attempt to upgrade to 1.12.1 instead of 1.11.0

> [upgrade/config] FATAL: invalid configuration: kind and apiVersion is
>   mandatory information that needs to be specified in all YAML documents

This is happening because you pass v1.12.1 to $VERSION while using below command:

```
export VERSION=$(curl -sSL https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)

root@kube-update-11:~# echo $VERSION
```

> v1.12.1

What you should do is manually set proper version:

```
export VERSION=v1.11.0
export ARCH=amd64
curl -sSL https://dl.k8s.io/release/${VERSION}/bin/linux/${ARCH}/kubeadm > /usr/bin/kubeadm
chmod a+rx /usr/bin/kubeadm
```

And try again

```
root@kube-update-11:~# kubeadm upgrade plan
```

> [preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
>
> [upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
>
> [upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
>
> [upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
>
> [upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl
>   -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
>
> I1022 12:07:11.188895   20089 feature_gate.go:230] feature gates:
>   &{map[]}
>
> [upgrade] Fetching available versions to upgrade to
>
> [upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.10.4
>
> [upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.11.0
>
> [upgrade/versions] Latest stable version: v1.12.1
>
> [upgrade/versions] Latest version in the v1.10 series: v1.10.9

```
root@kube-update-11:~# kubeadm upgrade apply v1.11.0
```

> [preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
>
> [upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
>
> [upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
>
> ...
>
> [upgrade/version] You have chosen to change the cluster version to
>   "v1.11.0"
>
> [upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.10.4
>
> [upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.11.0
>
> ...
>
> [upgrade/successful] SUCCESS! Your cluster was upgraded to "v1.11.0".
>   Enjoy!
>
> [upgrade/kubelet] Now that your control plane is upgraded, please
>   proceed with upgrading your kubelets if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thank you. The method worked well. I update to 1.9.11 --> 1.10.4 -->  1.10.9 --> 1.11.3   update to 1.12.1 not allowed. But I use make upgrade (ubuntu)  and cluster Master is 1.12.1.        I try update Node to 12.1 but after  node restart cluster master lost Node. Should the node be updated in a special way?

Comment: inspect this topic, maybe it will help you update to 1.12.1